# force heroku to avoid https

Tags: php, http, heroku, https

I have a PHP app in Heroku that references a javascript stored at a non-secure location.  My developer tools are telling me that they won't load "Mixed Content".

How do I get Heroku to serve over HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is served via HTTPS, there is no way you can force the external content to be loaded via HTTP. It would require a security downgrade, and the browsers refuses to perform such action.

The best solution is to make sure that even that JavaScript file is served via HTTPS. You can easily host it behind a proxy, or store somewhere where you can use HTTPS. Today is very easy to find an HTTPS-enabled storage system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you can achieve this on Heroku side. You have to manage this things on your side.

Thanks